# Adding multiple background image files to a deployable project

Tags: c#, image, resources

I looked and didn't see an answer that addressed my question. I have an application that uses a random file as the background image. I currently store these images in a folder on my local computer and walk the folder to load the image file names into a ArrayList, which works fine. However, I need a way to make this work when I deploy the app to a different computer.

So: 1) is there a way to deploy these images with the Visual Studio Publish functionality or 2) is there a way to add them to the Resources area of the project and them either add them to an Array(List) or walk through them? I do have other files (icons, etc.) in the Resources list that I would not want to include. I could use a series of IF statements to exclude them but that feels awful :) Any ideas you folks may have would be greatly appreciated.

Code that I'm currently using on my local machine:

```
    ArrayList bgImageList = new ArrayList();

    bgImageList = myIO.ProcessDirectory(bgImageFilePath);

    DisplayBackgroundImage();
    private void DisplayBackgroundImage()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int index = rnd.Next(0, bgImageList.Count);
        this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile((String)bgImageList[index]);
    }

class FileIO
{
    // Note: I think I found this code on this site. I cannot recall the author's name 
    // but all credit goes to them. I did modify it to return the ArrayList.

    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

    public ArrayList ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory)
    {
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            ProcessFile(fileName);

        string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);

        return myList;
    }

    private void ProcessFile(string path)
    {
        myList.Add(path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add your images to your project, and then, in the properties, set the `Copy to output directory` to Copy if newer
That should be enough to the Publish functionality include the files

if not, you can edit your .pubxml file
Add a new target

```
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="*.jpg" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>Resources\%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

And copy the files:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>CustomCollectFiles;
      </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>CustomCollectFiles;
      </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```